# Devise User Sign Up on Heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I'm using Devise to sign users up, which works on my localhost, but when I deploy the app to Heroku I get a dead page when I visit the users sign up page.

I have a modified registrations controller. I can access the log in page no problem.

Below are the logs:

```
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.924861+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
> devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.7ms)
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.926680+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:       
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.926678+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first_name' for
> #<User:0x007fb5f86244a8>): 2015-02-09T17:44:06.926709+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:12:in `block
> in
> _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2767088950509430214_70209766571260'
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.926711+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:7:in
> `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2767088950509430214_70209766571260'
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.926714+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.926713+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:5:in `new'
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.926715+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697819+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.926701+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:         <%=
> f.label :first_name %><br /> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697825+00:00
> app[web.1]:      9:        2015-02-09T17:44:06.686488+00:00
> app[web.1]: Processing by RegistrationsController#new as HTML
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.695917+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
> devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.9ms)
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697823+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first_name' for
> #<User:0x007fb5f8657a60>): 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697831+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:       </div> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697833+00:00
> app[web.1]:     14:        2015-02-09T17:44:06.697828+00:00
> app[web.1]:     11:         <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697834+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:       <div
> class="field"> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697827+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   
> <div class="field"> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697830+00:00 app[web.1]:    
> 12:         <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697836+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:12:in `block in
> _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2767088950509430214_70209766571260'
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697840+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:5:in `new'
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.922118+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
> shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.925025+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal
> Server Error in 9ms 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697839+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:7:in
> `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2767088950509430214_70209766571260'
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697842+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.913596+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET
> "/users/sign_up" for 140.203.249.251 at 2015-02-09 17:44:06 +0000
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.697843+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.741773+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/users/sign_up" host=www.lapseapp.co
> request_id=4d86fc5a-0554-45f2-8295-79369240721e fwd="140.203.249.251"
> dyno=web.1 connect=23ms service=41ms status=500 bytes=1754
> 2015-02-09T17:44:06.932492+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/users/sign_up" host=www.lapseapp.co
> request_id=06ee500f-54f4-404b-a024-7ec4ab7184b6 fwd="140.203.249.251"
> dyno=web.1 connect=11ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=1754
> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.821223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/users/sign_up" host=www.lapseapp.co
> request_id=a4847b4c-4964-4490-8726-6e045a0f88dd fwd="140.203.249.251"
> dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=500 bytes=1754
> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.817971+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
> shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.811058+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET
> "/users/sign_up" for 140.203.249.251 at 2015-02-09 17:49:06 +0000
> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.813015+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by
> RegistrationsController#new as HTML 2015-02-09T17:49:06.822040+00:00
> app[web.1]:     10:       <div class="field">
> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.822041+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:         <%=
> f.label :first_name %><br /> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.822043+00:00
> app[web.1]:     12:         <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus:
> true %> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.820319+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
> devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.6ms)
> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.820436+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal
> Server Error in 7ms 2015-02-09T17:49:06.822034+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.822036+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first_name' for
> #<User:0x007fb5f85dc2e8>): 2015-02-09T17:49:06.822038+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:        2015-02-09T17:49:06.822045+00:00
> app[web.1]:     13:       </div> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.822046+00:00
> app[web.1]:     14:        2015-02-09T17:49:06.822048+00:00
> app[web.1]:     15:       <div class="field">
> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.822051+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:12:in `block in
> _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2767088950509430214_70209766571260'
> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.822053+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:7:in
> `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2767088950509430214_70209766571260'
> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.822054+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:5:in `new'
> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.822056+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:49:06.822057+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:49:31.058835+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for
> 140.203.249.251 at 2015-02-09 17:49:31 +0000 2015-02-09T17:49:31.063413+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
> static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.4ms)
> 2015-02-09T17:49:31.061847+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by
> StaticPagesController#home as HTML 2015-02-09T17:49:31.064166+00:00
> app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
> 2015-02-09T17:49:31.065175+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 3ms
> (Views: 2.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) 2015-02-09T17:49:31.064739+00:00
> app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
> 2015-02-09T17:49:31.068932+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/" host=guarded-harbor-5264.herokuapp.com
> request_id=ef7ee4fe-8739-479a-a4dc-1452d80fd941 fwd="140.203.249.251"
> dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=3758
> 2015-02-09T17:49:31.704180+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/assets/application-2773672927f34d7f7089d016ab05e54d.css"
> host=guarded-harbor-5264.herokuapp.com
> request_id=f1443c12-920f-4b1c-86a2-1208f4d6868b fwd="140.203.249.251"
> dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=249ms status=200 bytes=38232
> 2015-02-09T17:49:31.750866+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/assets/application-be644bf15bf93ef34361c033d1949a77.js"
> host=guarded-harbor-5264.herokuapp.com
> request_id=9bd0242b-b36e-4f18-ae1d-4cb3c6826a90 fwd="140.203.249.251"
> dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=304ms status=200 bytes=64768
> 2015-02-09T17:49:32.674478+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/assets/bg3-c9d92c61064c79152bec9ea3dd8443ee.jpg"
> host=guarded-harbor-5264.herokuapp.com
> request_id=e7de7ba8-f26f-43d5-8da0-55e34e3ee3a0 fwd="140.203.249.251"
> dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1077ms status=200 bytes=876051
> 2015-02-09T17:49:33.676064+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/favicon.ico" host=guarded-harbor-5264.herokuapp.com
> request_id=c5ad4d36-5944-457e-aeaa-99b1a1e90501 fwd="140.203.249.251"
> dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=228
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470439+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/users/sign_up" host=guarded-harbor-5264.herokuapp.com
> request_id=80153935-795e-46d5-8a32-d5c3318959dc fwd="140.203.249.251"
> dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17ms status=500 bytes=1754
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.459092+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET
> "/users/sign_up" for 140.203.249.251 at 2015-02-09 17:49:35 +0000
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.466406+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
> shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.705964+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by
> RegistrationsController#new as HTML 2015-02-09T17:49:35.461438+00:00
> app[web.1]: Processing by RegistrationsController#new as HTML
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.468962+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
> devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.9ms)
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.469092+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal
> Server Error in 8ms 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470739+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470742+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first_name' for
> #<User:0x007fb5f815a8f0>): 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470744+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:        2015-02-09T17:49:35.470747+00:00
> app[web.1]:     11:         <%= f.label :first_name %><br />
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470745+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:       <div
> class="field"> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470752+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:   
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470749+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:         <%=
> f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true %>
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470750+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:       </div>
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470757+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:12:in `block in
> _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2767088950509430214_70209766571260'
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470758+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:7:in
> `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2767088950509430214_70209766571260'
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470753+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:       <div
> class="field"> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470760+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:5:in `new'
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470763+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.470762+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.698893+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET
> "/users/sign_up" for 140.203.249.251 at 2015-02-09 17:49:35 +0000
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.754648+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
> path="/users/sign_up" host=guarded-harbor-5264.herokuapp.com
> request_id=74c6f5b6-d19c-4f02-8c7a-a58ddf606506 fwd="140.203.249.251"
> dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=67ms status=500 bytes=1754
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.740666+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered
> shared/_error_messages.html.erb (12.3ms)
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.743786+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal
> Server Error in 38ms 2015-02-09T17:49:35.743587+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
> (35.6ms) 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753676+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753682+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:       
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753680+00:00 app[web.1]:
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first_name' for
> #<User:0x007fb5f811f0c0>): 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753683+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:       <div class="field">
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753691+00:00 app[web.1]:     14:       
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753692+00:00 app[web.1]:     15:       <div
> class="field"> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753685+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   
> <%= f.label :first_name %><br /> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753687+00:00
> app[web.1]:     12:         <%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus:
> true %> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753694+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:12:in `block in
> _app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2767088950509430214_70209766571260'
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753689+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:       </div>
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753697+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:5:in `new'
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753696+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb:7:in
> `_app_views_devise_registrations_new_html_erb___2767088950509430214_70209766571260'
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753699+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2015-02-09T17:49:35.753700+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error, it looks like the new.html.erb layout is referencing first_name field but the User object doesn't have that.

Edit: There is a chance that the gem you're working with locally is newer than heroku's or vice versa so I'd look for a culprit there if this isn't a simple logic error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it. In my case, I migrated a username to users table, but forgot to reset the production database.

Given my experience, this line in the error

```
> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `first_name' for
> #<User:0x007fb5f85dc2e8>)...
```

might have been caused by your recently-preformed migration.

If that is the case, the following steps will fix the problem:

```
$ heroku pg:reset DATABASE    # Reset the production database
$ heroku run rake db:migrate  # Inform Heroku of your new database schema
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the cause of it is that your local host has the users table populated with users, but once you deployed to Heroku, the users table is created from scratch and will be empty.

do the following:-

```
heroku login
heroku rake db:create
heroku rake db:migrate
```

then use the devise Sign_up and create a new user or whatever the registration form is.